# How to add nofollow site-wide

Tags: nofollow

I'd like to change the meta robot tag on my site to be `noindex` and `nofollow`. When I set the WP settings in "Search Engine Visibility" to "Discourage...", it only generates:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
```

How can I change it to `noindex` and `nofollow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One part of removing your site from Google is to add `<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />` to every page.  If you can edit the theme code then you could just add this to `header.php` (and any variants).

You could also use a plugin.  I've not tested any, but https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-robots-meta/ claims to do the job simply.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. Once I do it, what do I put in the robots.txt file? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok. So that will prevent Google from crawling the site. But will that de-index the pages? I want to first de-index the pages, then block it (via the robots.txt file). Thanks.

Comment: Following Gabriel's edits to your question I've rewritten my answer to suit.